# Git always asking for username and password even with using SSH key

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab

I have started an online Gitlab account to host some of my projects.

I have set up my account, generated my SSH key and entered this into the SSH Keys section of the Gitlab site. Whenever I attempt to git push, git pull or whatever I still get prompted for my username and password. I have followed the instructions on the Gitlab website to make sure I am not forgetting any steps and it still prompts me.

My key looks like this:

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDNoni9GhAESKyneV76Xp/bEc8Pb/eN4MxBrP6kfam9CjPADxrmtVeUFjnZuo+kgSRxAHvMiu6MqbINMQtCt9fNOrX0uCW0e5AoQwC9w1jz+JaReqWyw87A5Tk/4AOM6TZ1oY0R/uGgiFQaxkK1YWOxRrPcC+Lan/RawFflVeYYFzGOf8jcj+VhUk2TPewcZ6dPH3XL1op+Aau35VCs/FcaCPH/MKsrqMgx4blsvzjNLKUOkOYWyQP2wVsLdyKH4vUE9ISsZZWTgQoOfqEqD/VdugOUrxw9EorN7bFMHF4dY5AHTPIgWobo7Qw6ZJczIEF6Wgdrcc1L1JZoXeGvgIFL james.alex.holman@gmail.com
```

Is there any other things that may be causing this?

I am using Linux and terminal to generate these commands
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using http/https as your remote url.
Change it to ssh and it will not ask you for username password again.

Check your remote url, you might be using https

```
git remote -v
```

---

Http/https will ask yo for password every time you try to `fetch | pull| push` etc.

SSH is not using username/password nut use the ssh keys instead.

Using ssh your connection is secured using the ssh keys exchange.

[image]

Comment: is it http or https?

Comment: This is your problem, Set the remote url to ssh://git@... and it will work for you.

Comment: Go to the server and copy the clone url, update your local remote url and update it.

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks. I shall do this now.

Comment: @codeWizard Can you explain why https doesn't work so this answer is more useful?

Comment: Http is not secured and is not using the ssh keys, only ssh protocol use it in this case